# Combine setsid with .bshrc alias or launcher

Tags: command-line, bash, launcher

To run program X, I currently have to type `path/to/folder/X` in my terminal. I made an alias in my .bshrc so I can type `X` directly, and I have created a launcher so I can access X directly from my GUI. However, with both methods I have a terminal screen running along side X, doing nothing.

If I type `setsid path/to/folder/X;sleep 10;exit`, X runs independent of the terminal and the terminal closes automatically (if I don't put the sleep 10, appearantly setsid does not have enough time to start X). However, I can't find a way to 'shortcut' this command, either in my terminal or in a launcher. Plugging the above line into a launcher doesnt work, and setsid doesnt recognize .bshrc aliasses.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're doing or why you chose such a complex way. All you need to do is add `path/to/folder/` to your `PATH` variable (that is the list of directories that will be searched for executables). Edit `~/.profile` and add this line:

```
PATH=$PATH:path/to/folder/
```

Now you will be able to run `X` directly, be it from the commandline or a launcher. Alternatively, point your launcher (I guess you mean .desktop file) to `path/to/folder/`. Assuming this is a GUI program, there's no reason to have a terminal associated with it.

Comment: Thank you! I am pretty new to the Linux environment, as you might have guessed ;) Adding the folder to my path works, and I can now run `setsid X` from my terminal.  Putting `setsid` in my launcher (.desktop) still does not work, but that's a minor inconvenience.

Comment: @Scipio just forget about setsid altogether. I still have no idea why you're using it. To make a launcher, just give it the full path to X.